# CSS issue, lots of empty space to the right end of website

Tags: html, css

Hey guys Im having an issue where I get lots of empty space to the right end of my website, I tried editing the widths but that wouldnt resolve the issue and im pretty stuck, would appreciate any help! thank you!

```
div.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 625px;
}

div.menu {
    position: relative;
    left: 39%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

hr {
  border-top: 5px solid #111111; 
  border-bottom: 5px solid #292929; 
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}'
#details_product_box {
    position:relative;
    left:-300px;


}
#description_box {
    position:relative; 
    top:-350px;
    left:580px;
    width: 200px;
}

#products_box {
    width:900px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

    #single_product {
        float:left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #shopping_cart {
        width:800px;
        height:50px;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

li.select {
    float: left;
}

.product_text {
    text-align: center;

}





<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
<hr>
    <?php cart(); ?>
    <div id="shopping_cart">
        <span style="float:left;">Welcome Guest | Total Items: <?php total_items();?> <b style="colour:blue;">| Total: £<?php total_price(); ?></b> <a href="cart.php">Go to Cart: </a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="select"><a href="main.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="select"><a href="basket.html">BASKET </a></li>
            <li class="select"><a href="summary.html">OUR WORLD </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("csmysql.cs.cf.ac.uk", "c1546910",
                         "sebastian1", "c1546910");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM MrPiece";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        $ip=getIp(); 

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $pro_id = $row['ID'];
                $product_name = $row['Name'];
                $product_price = $row['Price'];
                $product_image = $row['Image'];

                echo "<div id='products_box'>";
                echo "<div id='single_product'>";

                echo "<img src='$product_image' style='height:250px; width:180px'> <br>";
                echo "<a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>$product_name</a><br>";
                echo "£ $product_price <br>";
                echo "<a href='main.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button style='float: center;'>Add to cart</button></a>";

                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
        else {echo "No results";}
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: can you put an image to show how it looks like?

Comment: please show you markup and a reproducible example

Comment: http://imgur.com/DO79lq2    my bad about previous one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the inspector, try removing parts of the HTML until the empty space disappears. This is what I do to first identify which element on the page is causing the problem.

After that look at what might be causing the problem in the CSS on the element or its children. If you can't find the cause, maybe you can set up an example (https://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you and Patrick, Im just getting used to css, I went to work with the inspector and managed to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `left: 39%;` on your `div.menu` style.

If you're trying to center your menu there are better ways to do it than using

```
div.menu {
    position: relative;
    left: 39%;
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7j9vqj7/1/)